# Multiple values for AfterTargets in .proj file

Tags: msbuild, proj

One of my projects has `Exec Copy` command to copy a file from one directory to another. We are intermittently seeing an issue where one of the process is locking a file and MsBuild is trying to execute a copy command on the same file. So, we are facing the error that the file is in use by another process.

We are suspecting that this is because of two different elements executing in parallel. Unless the first one finishes we do not want the second one to execute. Can we have two values for AfterBuild attribute like below.

Below are the projects: Project1.proj and Project2.proj. I want to use the target defined in Project2 into Project1. Project1.proj has a reference added for Projet2.proj

`Project1.proj`

`<Target Name="TestTarget" AfterTargets="Build;TestTargetAnother" > ..... ..... </Target>`

`Project2.proj`

`<Target Name="TestTargetAnother" AfterTargets="Build" > ..... ..... </Target>`

Comment: Did you want to make one of the two targets execute and when one executes, disable the other?

Comment: Hi om dev, any update about this issue? Please check if the  answer helps  you handle the issue?

Comment: Hi @PerryQian-MSFT,
These project files have multiple other elements, so I couldn't find a way to make them .targets files and test your changes.

Comment: You can first enter your project's csproj file, and then find any import node which is your reference files' path. Then change them to `.targets`. You just change the reference proj files to targets. targets is more normalized.

Comment: And progress about it?

Answer (score 0):

> We are suspecting that this is because of two different elements
> executing in parallel. Unless the first one finishes we do not want
> the second one to execute.

**First**, rename your two files as `Project1.targets` and `Project2.targets`.

The file with `proj` suffix cannot be used in other referenced files. Files with this suffix cannot transfer properties.

Modify `Project1.targets` like this:

```
<Project>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Flag>false</Flag>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name="TestTarget" AfterTargets="Build;TestTargetAnother" Condition="'$(Flag)'=='false'">

        <Exec Command="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <Flag>true</Flag>
        </PropertyGroup>

    </Target>

    <Import Project="Project2.targets"/>

</Project>
```

**Then**, modify `Project2.targets` like this:

```
<Project>
    
    
<Target Name="TestTargetAnother" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Flag)'=='false'">
<Exec Command="xxxxxxxx"/>
<PropertyGroup>
     <Flag>true</Flag>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
</Project>
```

**After that**, reference `Project1.targets` into your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
 <Import Project="Project1.targets" />
```

**So** it will execute one of them and cancel the other.